# Concat variable on SSIS create table SQL task

Tags: ssis

I am running a Execute SQL Task that creates a "RunID" everytime it is executed.  I have 30+ tables that I wish to create and name table_RunID every time the package is run.  I cannot quite figure out how (if it is even possible) I can concat the RunID onto the create sql text.  I have read how I can create a variable based off an expression that contains the whole sql script, but since I have many tables I'd love to just concat it in the create table script instead of creating a table

Comment: why on earth are you creating tables on the fly in an SSIS package? Why not have staging table that include the run id as a column and hold multiple runs?

Comment: We initially had this idea, but want to avoid having table's bloated.  We still want a few runs of the old tables for historical purposes and use a "most recent" view to look into the most recently created tables.

Comment: To get it to work as you're wanting, you're likely going to be looking at writing dynamic SQL within an Execute SQL Task